# Frequency domain S11 conversion to time domain TDR

Tags: tdr

Below we see the S11 plot of a transmission line, the Wikipedia definition of the reflection coefficient as a function of S-params.

As I see it, the S-param frequency domain plot comes from the time domain steady state.

TDR is time domain in every moment from the start (transient).

So how can we convert from S-param (steady state) to TDR (transient)?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: "TDR" means "time domain reflectometry" and you seem to be implying there is a specific formula directly attached to the phrase "TDR". TDR is a technique rather than a formula but, I'm prepared to be wrong so please explain what it is. Maybe you are looking to convert an S parameter to a reflection coefficient?

Comment: Hello Andy ,yes you are correct,by TDR i mean the moment impedance coming to a node using bounce diagram.(transient).
i know that in order to convert impedance to S11 and vise versa we use the following formula in the following link:
https://ibb.co/qB2hKsf 

But S11 is a frequency domain diagram(which i assume come from steady state)

so i cant see how its possible to convert between the moment impedance and S11,the one is steady state where moment impedance is transient.

Comment: You can convert S11 to \$\Gamma_r\$ directly but you cannot know the impedance in the frequency domain because it can have two values. Neither can you use the transient impedance values in the time domain to extract what the frequency domain impedances are. They are different things. You can however, look at the transient signals and estimate what the frequency domain impedance will be (a little tortuous).

Comment: exactly ,that what i am trying to understand.
because we have a formula linking reflection coefficient and impedance shown in the link bellow:
https://ibb.co/N9FrWgZ
but you say that its not the reflection coefficient from S11.
why they are not the same?
Could you please explain to the difference between gamma in S11 and Gamma for transient impedance?
Thanks.

Comment: This is also untrue: *As i see it S-param frequency domain plot comes from time domain steady state.* - the S parameter is done by measuring impedance with a sinewave applied so that the accumulated effect of reflections settles down to an impedance mismatch rather than a bunch of complicated transient reflections.

Comment: I'm not going to start explaining anything if I don't understand the basic premise of your question. That comes first. You must be clearer as to what it is you don't understand so that me (and others) can make an answer to what you have written in your question.

Comment: You should also make your opening sentence easier to understand. Grammatically it doesn't make sense. What has Wikipedia got to do with this ? Is there punctuation missing or maybe you forgot something in that sentence? You should also not use the term TDR if you are not talking about time domain reflectometry - that is a specialist case when trying to ascertain where a cable has impedance anomalies.

Comment: Hello Andy,my main question is how can we look at S11 plot and see a rise in values and say that "here is a problem" and then go to transient impedance TDR to look for the source of it. If S11 is steady state and transient impedance is transient.We cant do it if one if steady steade and the other is transient.

Comment: I don't know what this means : *then go to transient impedance TDR to look for the source of it* - I don't recognize the usage of TDR here or what equipment you might be using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the time domain TDR by taking the inverse transform of the frequency domain S11 data. This is related to the fact that the impulse response of a network is equal to the Fourier transform of its frequency response. Many Vector Network Analyzers have this function built in and usually labeled "Transform". You can find the details by Googling "convert S11 data to TDR". One good source is: https://cdn.rohde-schwarz.com/pws/dl_downloads/dl_application/application_notes/1ez44/1ez44_0e.pdf.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

By taking an Inverse Fourier Transform, it's possible to convert S11 measurements from a VNA to its equivalent time-domain response as measured by a TDR. Previously, this capability is often exclusive in expensive simulation packages or in the firmware of expensive VNAs. Now, with the power of [scikit-rf](http://scikit-rf.org/), a free and open source Python software library for RF/microwave modeling and analysis, it's accessible to everyone with basic programming knowledge.

Here's a demo from my recent experiment (this is only meant to be a quick example, the measurement is not fully calibrated and the parameters used for the calculations are not optimized, so please don't complain too much about the data).

To evaluate the impedance discontinuity and signal integrity impact caused by a 1206 resistor footprint, I fabricated a test fixture shown in the picture below.

[image: PCB test board]

[image: resistor footprint, with ground plane partially removed]

It's a 4-layer circuit board with three solid ground planes. Two through-hole SMA connectors are located on both ends, with a 50-ohm microstrip in between. At the center is the Device Under Test, a 0-ohm, 1206 resistor. Also, to compensate for the excess capacitance caused by the large resistor pads, the ground plane under the resistor body is partially removed.

After I've received the board, I measured its S11 from 10 MHz to 4 GHz using a Vector Network Analyzer. It shows the return loss is good up to 1.2 GHz. But is it the full picture?

[image: Measured S11 data]

Using the scikit-rf software library and the following Python code, we can transform the data from frequency domain to time domain.

```
import sys
import skrf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
skrf.stylely()

network = skrf.Network(sys.argv[1])
network_dc = network.extrapolate_to_dc(kind='linear')

plt.figure()
plt.title("Time Domain Reflectometry")
network_dc.s11.plot_z_time_step(window='hamming', label="impedance")
plt.xlim((-0.5, 1.5))

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: TDR plot]

This calculated TDR plot immediately reveals that the test fixture was poorly designed with non-ideal SMA-to-microstrip transitions. When the signal hits the first SMA connector, the instantaneous impedance drops to 45 ohms due to a capacitive discontinuity, then it hits the 50-ohm trace, hits the device-under-test, hits the 50-ohm trace again, and finally hits the second connector.

In fact, after de-embedding, it turned out that the resistor footprint only has 20 dB return loss at 800 MHz, not 1.2 GHz. The bad SMA connector footprints and the resistor footprint actually compensated each other. It would be difficult to spot this problem using the Smith Chart, on the other hand, it's obvious from the computed TDR response.

You can find more information from scikit-rf's documentation, [Time domain reflectometry, measurement vs simulation](https://scikit-rf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/networktheory/Time%20domain%20reflectometry%2C%20measurement%20vs%20simulation.html). scikit-rf also supports time-gating, it's possible to use time-gating as a simple way to de-embed the connectors from the DUT by deleting the reflections from the time domain, see [Time Domain and Gating](https://scikit-rf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/networktheory/Time%20Domain.html).

Comment: Do you have the source input of s1p in this example? So that I can test the TDR result with the code. Appreciate.

Comment: @yancyn No problem, you can download it from [here](https://tomli.blog/ftp/x-resistor.s1p). Alternatively, you can also use the data from the official scikit-rf example instead (linked at the end of my answer). Its raw data for that example is located in scikit-rf's official code repository: https://github.com/scikit-rf/scikit-rf/tree/master/doc/source/examples/networktheory/tdr_measurement_vs_simulation

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can download Copper Mountain VNA control software (such as S2VNA) which can run in demo mode (without VNA connected). Software allows importing S1P data and postprocessing it with time domain / gating analysis free of charge.

Here's an example of S11 data of a ~200mm long RG174 cable with SMA connectors on both ends, obtained with a 8.5 GHz Agilent E5071C when using Copper Mountain S2VNA Control software:

[image]